# Counter denies to counter at Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a current counter that works on Firefox so far, but I noticed that when You open it at Google Chrome, the focus isn't automatically there, where at Firefox it does.

Is there a solution that works better than an iframe checking for it?

Code:

```
var count = 0;
var myInterval;
// Active
window.addEventListener('focus', startTimer);

// Inactive
window.addEventListener('blur', stopTimer);

function timerHandler() {
count++;
document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = count;
}

// Start timer
function startTimer() {
console.log('focus');
myInterval = window.setInterval(timerHandler, 1000);
}

// Stop timer
function stopTimer() {
window.clearInterval(myInterval);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grbq7uzj/

What I want is the following:
You visit the website by just entering the url, then the website pops up with the counter start counting.

How it is in Firefox is just like I said above.

But in Google Chrome this happens:
After entering the url and press enter, the website pops up but the counter stays at 0. When you change the tab for a second and then go to the tab with the counter in it, it starts counting.

So There must me a trigger solution, that also starts counting after visiting the website.

Comment: Can you give a complete demo of what you are working with please? Maybe a code snippet or a [**JsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net) Thank you. **ALSO** Have you checked for errors in the console for chrome?

Comment: Added it @NewToJS

Comment: No errors whatsoever, It works only when you change to other tab and then back to the real tab where the counter is. But is should automatically start counting if you visit the website.

Comment: @Prizen . you have to click on the window for `focus` to be triggered.. I think you are you trying to make it working when you hover over the screen, am I right?

Comment: Exactly but on Firefox nothing is needed then just opening the website with the counter in it.

Comment: All seems to be working fine for me too but from reading the comments above maybe try using a `window.onload` event to execute a function to set the focus on that element? Maybe that could work.... Hard for me to know since all seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: window.onload doesnt work sadly enough.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do! better if you describe what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: @msoliman Added it in startpost.